# Plotting with matplotlib - trying to conserve my scale order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following list :

```
[1, 2, 3, 17, 16, 4, 7, 6, 13, 12, 5, 24]
```

these have associated values:

```
[6.254484668288452e-08,
 0.48735364325982383,
 2.691646548287535e-07,
 4.746326705218297e-15,
 4.889505772899467e-19, ...]
```

I wish to plot these values using `plt.scatter`
However when plotting the xscale [1,2,3,17,16 etc...] is obviously set to be in order and thus looses the specific meaning i'm attemping to broadcast. I wish to keep this order while plotting is there a way to do this?

I have plotted like this but its not doing it how I wish.

```
plt.scatter(lst1, lst2, s=50)
plt.xticks(lst1)
y=[0.05 for a in range(24)] # necessary for me to show significance
plt.plot(x,y,"r+")
plt.show()
```

Comment: maybe `plt.scatter(map(str, lst1), lst2)`?  If not, what's your expected output?

Comment: Should probably be `plt.scatter(list(map(str, lst1)), lst2)` otherwise I get an error saying "matplotlib does not support generators as input"

Comment: @not_speshal Thank you! This has worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert your first list to text labels.

Probably something like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 17, 16, 4, 7, 6, 13, 12, 5, 24]
x_ticks_label = ["{}".format(i) for i in x]
plt.xticks(x, xticks_label)
```

This is somehow I dealt with displaying a datetime object as time only.